# Xamarin SocketIoClientDotNet xhr poll error

Tags: xamarin, socket.io, header

I'm currently developing a chat application using Xamarin.Forms. I added the following libraries as the project references:

- EngineIOClient.Net
- SocketIOClientDotNet
- WebSocket4Net

I managed to establish a connection and exchange messages with the server. The issue is that at one point in development, the production environment is requiring additional headers not only for HTTPS requests but also for socket messages. As a result, I always get "xhr poll error" message in this event:

```
  _socket.On(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, (data) =>
            {
                //Do something here
            });
```

I tried to find an example how to add a header to my socket instance but without any luck. I looked at an Android example for soket.io and it seems straightforward:

```
socket.io().on(Manager.EVENT_TRANSPORT, new Emitter.Listener() {

@Override public void call(Object... args) { 
Transport transport = (Transport)args[0];

transport.on(Transport.EVENT_REQUEST_HEADERS, new Emitter.Listener() {
  @Override
  public void call(Object... args) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Map<String, List<String>> headers = (Map<String, List<String>>)args[0];
    // modify request headers
    headers.put("Cookie", Arrays.asList("foo=1;"));
  }
});

transport.on(Transport.EVENT_RESPONSE_HEADERS, new Emitter.Listener() {
  @Override
  public void call(Object... args) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Map<String, List<String>> headers = (Map<String, List<String>>)args[0];
    // access response headers
    String cookie = headers.get("Set-Cookie").get(0);
  }
});
```

}
});

I tried to implement a similar code in C#:

```
 _socket.Io().On("transport", o =>
                {

                    Transport transport = (Transport)o;
                    transport.On(Transport.EVENT_REQUEST_HEADERS, new ListenerImpl(o1 =>
                    {
                        var headers = (Dictionary<string, List<string>>)o1;
                        headers.Add("MyHeader", new List<string> { "MyHeaderValue" });
                    }));

                    transport.On(Transport.EVENT_RESPONSE_HEADERS, new ListenerImpl(o2 =>
                    {
                        var headers = (Dictionary<string, List<string>>)o2;

                    }));
                });
```

but the transport event is never trigged. Is it possible to add headers to socket connection with this library? Am I missing something?